OANDA pricing stream - only bids/asks?
I am probably missing or misunderstanding something fundamental here, about OANDA or forex in general, but...
OANDA v20 REST API has these two endpoints for getting instrument prices:
/v3/accounts/{accountID}/pricing/stream 
/v3/accounts/{accountID}/pricing 

Both of these endpoints return data of type ClientPrice which contains bids and asks.
But how do I get the prices of executed trades?  You know, the "prints".
